# How to simulate WSAEWOULDBLOCK on blocking send()?

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock, send

I'm trying to simulate WSAEWOULDBLOCK on blocking send() with setsockopt by reducing the internal Winsock send buffer to a very small value and 2 threads sending at same time...

Droping the connection by unplug the network cable or block it in the firewall is not sufficient to fill up the internal send buffer and return the WSAEWOULDBLOCK ?

How can I do this ?

Thank's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accept the connection on the remote end, but [tarpit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarpit_%28networking%29) at that location. Keep trying to send on the local end, and you should be able to fill up the data buffer used for outgoing traffic.

Comment: How to tarpit in the source ? Sleep at recv() looping ? I've tryed tarpiting (one way) in MikroTik RouterOS but without success, the client hang send() with WSAECONNRESET.

I don't remember where I see that Windows 7 resize the socket buffers automaticaly and internaly. That's can be the reason that I never can fill up the send buffer ?

Comment: Yeah, accept() the connection and just sleep on the remote end.

Comment: Now I get it. Windows 7 have 16KB of send buffer size. When I send more then that, the send() "blocks" until all the data goes to the kernel, but if I try to make 2 send() calls, where the last send size is bigger than 16KB, then the second send() returns WSAEWOULDBLOCK. Even if I put the sleep() after accept() in the remote end, the local keeps sending the data (weird)...